# Getting Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysop - styles.sss

Tags: css, sass

Earlier I typed `sass --watch styles.sss:styles.css` instead of `.scss`

I then cancelled that watch using control + C which I assumed stopped the watch. Then I redid using the correct file.

Now when I go to open it in my browser I get this error

> Getting Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysop -
>   styles.sss.

It seems to still be watching the styles.sss which does not exist.

I have tried restarting the terminal and re-doing the watch but still haven't had any luck. I also read on another stack overflow that "clearing the system" worked for someone else. However, I do not know what that would entail or even how to go about doing that. So far I have uninstalled sass and re-installed it with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you use the correct file extension?  Sass files should use either .scss or .sass extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure any sass process is stopped, run the command:

```
killall sass
```

Repeat until you get the message:

```
sass: no process found
```

If you get that message directly, you can try to make sure if the process is still alive under another name, by using `ps`

```
ps -u $(whoami) | grep sass
```

If there are still lingering processes, kill them with `kill {pid}`, where `{pid}` is the process id listed in ps.

If the processes keep running, pass `-9` to the kill command, so it sends the KILL signal rather than the default `TERM`, which is more effective in killing than terminating. The difference in semantics is another topic ;)

But, I don't think a running process is the issue. You're probably either watching a browser cache, or you should simply try to remove the compile result, or rename the source file and try a different name. Sass tends to give error message in the console output also, so you shouldn't be in the dark about whether stuff gets compiled or not.